# Recursion, Explicit Equasion

Tags: induction, recursion

Prove $\ a_{n}<2^{n} $ for every natural number n, where $\ a_{n} $ is defined recursively by $$ a_{1}=1, a_{2}=2, a_{3}=3, a_{n}=a_{n-3}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1},\ for\   n>=4$$
Once I get the explicit equation, proving this would be easy with induction, however I'm having trouble finding it. I can't find the connection between these guys $\ a_{4}=6, a_{5}=11, a_{6}=20, a_{7}=37 $.

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use induction right on the recursion. We get $$a_n<2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}=2^{n-3}(5)<2^{n-3}(8)=2^n$$

The only good way to find an explicit formula would be to use generating functions. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function

Comment: Nevermind, don't bother trying to get the explicit formula: see this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a_n%3Da_%28n-1%29%2Ba_%28n-2%29%2Ba_%28n-3%29

Comment: Don't bother with the explicit formula, see this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a_n%3Da_%28n-1%29%2Ba_%28n-2%29%2Ba_%28n-3%29

Comment: Thanks for saving me the time trying to find the ex-formula. But I don't under stand how you can use induction on the recursion. You can prove it for n=4, assume a_(n)<2^(n) is true, but you can't prove it for a_(n+1) because you have a_(n-2), a_(n-1) which we dont know if they're true

Comment: There's a slight variation of induction that goes like: assume that the statement is true for *all* numbers $<n$, and show it holds for $n$. It is still a valid proof that way.

Comment: You're right! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. And remember that induction technique it's a useful trick - when I first learned I thought the same thing, that you only got one assumption, but you can actually assume everything below $n$! (exclamation, not factorial :)

Comment: XD I sure will!

Answer (score 1):

To estimate $a_n$
where
$a_{1}=1, a_{2}=2, a_{3}=3, a_{n}=a_{n-3}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1},\ for\   n>=4$,
suppose $a_k < c^k$
for $k < n$.

Then
$a_n < c^{n-1}+c^{n-2}+c^{n-3}
= c^n(1/c+1/c^2+1/c^3)$
and
$a_n < c^n$
if
$1/c+1/c^2+1/c^3 < 1$.
Since this is true for $c=2$,
this proves the result,
and shows that a smaller $c$ can be used,
up to where
$1/c+1/c^2+1/c^3 = 1$
(which has a root at
$c_0 \sim 1.8393$).

We can similarly establish an lower bound
of the form $a_n > b c^n$ like this:

Suppose $a_k > bc^k$
for $k < n$.
(The purpose of the additional variable $b$
is to allow the initial inequality
to be established.)

Then
$a_n > b(c^{n-1}+c^{n-2}+c^{n-3})
= b c^n(1/c+1/c^2+1/c^3)$
and
$a_n > bc^n$
if
$1/c+1/c^2+1/c^3 > 1$.
Since this is true for $c=1.8 < c_0$,
this proves the result,
and shows that any $c$
less than $c_0$
can be used.

This is just a way of discovering that
the $a_n$ grow like $c_0^n$.

Look up generating functions for
limear recurrences 
and the valuable and free book
Generatingfunctionology
from
http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html.